# Getting Element from parent / child relationship using Java (Groovy) Streams?

Tags: java, groovy, java-stream

I am using an API which has a bunch of objects with a parent / child relationship with the parent having a `getChildren` method to return a list of children.

Each object has an ID (via a `getId` method) and I know the ID of the object I want, I just have no idea where it is in the hierarchy.

Currently I am using recursion and building up a map if IDs to objects

```
def buildMap(obj, map) {
  for (c in obj.getChildren()) {
    map[c.getId()] = c
    buildMap(cs, map)
  }
}


def map = [:]
def root = obj.getRoot()
map[root.getId()] = root
buildMap(root, map)

def objIWant = map["someId"]
```

Is there a nicer way to implement this using streams?

Comment: What is `cs` in `map[c.getId()] = cs`?

Comment: A typo.  Should have just been `c`.   I have edited

Comment: There's really no "nicer" way to do this. You need this recursive method. The only thing you should add is a break statement where the ID you're looking for is found. You can use a stream if you make that method return a list of pairs rather than update the map in-place, but that adds no value imo.